# get json from database In a special way

Tags: python, mysql, json

i use python and mysql.connector
this is my code

```
 mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall();
json_data=[] 
for x in myresult:
    json_data.append(x)
print(json.dumps(json_data))# CREATE JSON
```

and get me result :

```
[[1, 61, 8585, "80000000"], [3, 61, 5151, "200"], [4, 61, 8585, "20"]]
```

but i need this :

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "sample": "61",
            "Price": "80000000",
            "name": "----"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "sample": "61",
            "Price": "200",
            "name": "ali"

        }
    ]
}
```

what can i do ?
Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write another function that parses your sql output into the json format. something like this:

```
def json_parser(sql_data):
    data_dict = {}
    list_of_rows = []
    for record in sql_data:
       dict1 = {}
       dict1['id'] = record[0] 
       dict1['sample'] = record[1] 
       dict1['Price'] = record[2]
       dict1['name'] = record[3]
       list_of_rows.append(dict1)
    data_dict['data'] = list_of_rows
```